# proving an algebraic set is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$X=\{{t,t^2}|t\in \mathbb{C}\} \subset \mathbb{C^2}$. Show that $X$ is an irreducible set.

Trying to put $X=A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are algebraic sets. I have to show either $X=A$ or $X=B$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm confused. Your first line asks to show that $X$ is an algebraic set, and the rest of your question asks to show it's irreducible. Do you need help with both, or just one?

Comment: sorry it would be irreducible

Answer (score 3):

Your $X$ is the image of the morphism $\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb A^2$ sending $t\mapsto (t,t^2)$. This corresponds to the $\mathbb C$-algebra map $\phi:\mathbb C[x,y]\to \mathbb C[t]$ sending $x\mapsto t,\,y\mapsto t^2$. We have: $$X=V(\ker\phi)=V(y-x^2).$$ This algebraic set is irreducible, since $(y-x^2)\subset \mathbb C[x,y]$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: how do you show it is a prime ideal ?

Comment: The polynomial $y-x^2$ is irreducible.

Comment: how do you show $y-x^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: You cannot write it as a product of two nonconstant polynomials. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short proof: since $X= \{ (t,t^2) \}$ for $t \in \mathbb C$, $X$ contains the torus $\mathbb C ^\ast$ as a dense open subset. The torus is irreducible, hence $X$ must be as well.